# Search for Transliteration tables

Tags: internationalization, transliteration

If your native language is not EN_US or you  know any other spoken language just fine you can easily contribute!)

**The Arabic Alphabet and Its Transliteration**

[image: The Arabic Alphabet and Its Transliteration (gif)]
<sub>(source: [narod.ru](http://superior0.narod.ru/key.jpg))</sub>

**The Bulgarian Alphabet and Its Transliteration**

[image: The Bulgarian Alphabet and Its Transliteration (gif)]

**Wanted!**
**

```
Bahasa Indonesia
Bahasa Melayu
Català
Česky
Dansk
Deutsch
Eesti
Ελληνικά
Español
Esperanto
Euskara
فارسی
Français
Galego
עברית
Hrvatski
Italiano
한국어
Lietuvių
Magyar
Nederlands
日本語
Norsk (bokmål)
Norsk (nynorsk)
Polski
Português
Română
Русский
Slovenčina
Slovenščina
Српски / Srpski
Suomi
Svenska
ไทย
Tiếng Việt
Türkçe
Українська
中文
```

Comment: There is no single tranliteration for any single language. There are, for example, about 5 standards for representing Arabic in the latin alphabet, several for Chinese, a few for Koren, etc. And this is not a programming question.

Comment: I wonder to see at least one of each -  1 for Chinese, one for Koren, etc. If there are more - I'll love to see them 2!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many transliteration systems for Ukrainian can be found [**on this page**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Ukrainian). Similarly, Wikipedia can help you with other languages as well :)

P.S. Probably the best transliteration table for Ukrainian:
[image: TCNS (ТКПН) Transliteration of Ukrainian (developed in 1994)]
<sub>(source: [translit.kh.ua](http://translit.kh.ua/TCNS_Ukrainian_transliteration.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For Arabic I actually recommend using [SATTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Arabic_Technical_Transliteration_System), which only uses characters that appear on standard US keyboard. No need of italics to differentiate letters which is just confusing. I used to be able to type in SATTS as fast as english, so I think it is a good system.

Answer (score 0):

I can transliterate Russian for you.

Russian alphabet (Русский Алфавит)

А а - A a

Б б - B b

В в - V v

Г г - G g

Д д - D d

Е е - similar to the English e, but it makes a "ye" sound, like in the Russian word, привет (means hello), pronounced "privyet"

Ё ё - doesn't have a literal translation, makes a "yo" sound.

Ж ж - zh similar to the sound of the s in pleasure

З з - Z z

И и - I i (pronounced like e, as in taxi

Й й - Y y

К к - K k

Л л - L l

М м - M m

Н н -N

О о - O o

П п - P p

Р р - R r

С с - S Т т - T t

У у - U u

Ф ф - F f

Х х - H h

Ц ц - not a literal translation, makes a "ts" sound

Ч ч - again not a literal translation, makes a "ch" sound

Ш ш -makes a "sh" sound

Щ щ - makes a "sht" sound (most English speakers have a hard time differentiating the ш and щ)

Ъ - not an actual letter, it is called the hard sign, it creates a pause between syllables, like in the Russian word, подъем ( which mean rise), pronounced like "pod-yem"

Ы ы - I i similar to the letter и, but not pronounced with an e sound, more like the I sound in the word "it"

Ь - soft sign, like the hard sign, it has no sound, the soft sign makes the previous letter soft, like the word сказать, (which means to say) would be written like -skazat' - and the t would have a less pronounced sound

Ю ю -  more like and "uh" sound unlike the letter У, which has a long u sound

Я я - pronounced like "ya"